# Jquery UI Autocomplete showing ID

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery UI for showing my autocomplete. when i type it works fine until i realize something buggy:

When i type and the data list show up, i press arrow key on my keyboard (up or down arrow) and on the textbox show up the ID, not the label.

```
$("#artwork").autocomplete({
    source: "{!! route('admin.theme.getart') !!}",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        $("[name='artwork_id']").val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

how to fixing this bug?

Comment: any code/screen shot?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee i can't take screenshot, when i press scrnsht the autocomplete gone. i add my code at my question

Comment: instead of `$("[name='artwork_id']").val(ui.item.value);`..use ``$("[name='artwork_id']").val(ui.item.label);``

Comment: @Pawan nooo, that command is used for when i click the autocomplete value, textbox named artwork_id filled by the autocomplete id for filling the data at database

Answer (score 5):

I add focus condition at autocomplete

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.value = ui.item.label;
    $("[name='artwork_id']").val(ui.item.value);
}
```